# Why Attribute list empty in olap connection: SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2016, olap, ssas-tabular

SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services.
I have connection to SQL Server 2016.

I use `DATABASE.GETBYNAME` function, the function returns me the db with cube & attribute empty list .

When I try to connect to SQL Server 2012, it works fine.

What can be the problem?

**ADD CODE**

> Database db = XServer.Databases.GetByName(databaseName);
> db.Dimensions - is empty when i ask 2016 and full when 2012
>
> its happen because it change from Analysis Services Scripting Language(XMLA) to Tabular Model Scripting Language (TMSL) - how can i handle this ?

Comment: Please edit your question - there is no need to put the entire text in a comment. Welcome to SatckOverflow :)

Comment: I need more context and a larger code snippet. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: basically i tried to How to automate SSAS tabular model processing in SQL Server 2016ץץץ